# How to get the all array in relation model in Larave?

Tags: laravel

How to get all the array in relations model. It supposed to be 3 records in relation `service`, I can fetch all the services of doctor if per one record, but if I will display all the doctor with services, the services per doctor displaying only one.

In my controller

```
 $doctors = User::with('reviews', 'services')->role('Doctor')->where('clinic_id', $id)->get();
```

**User** Model

```
 public function services()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(Service::class, 'id', 'doctor_id');
 }
```

[image]

This is the structure of service table
[image]

I've tried hasMany but relation service is empty

Comment: belongsTo would mean the User's table has the foreign key to services ... does services and users both have foreign keys to one another?

Comment: no foreign key for services in users table.

Comment: there has to be otherwise the `belongsTo` would not work at all ... for it to work there would have to be a key on the table for the model User that links to the table for the model Service ... but this services table also has foreign keys it looks like so not sure what you actual setup is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your relation in User model to hasMany as Doctor has many services
per your table structure.

```
public function services()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Service::class, 'doctor_id', 'id');
}
```

and in Service model use belongsTo

Comment: that's what i did with has many I'm getting empty data

Comment: I have updated code you have to check it now.